# Android: CheckBoxPreference icon doesn't show on <3.0?

Tags: android

I am using a CheckBoxPrefence with an icon.  The icon shows properly on ICS, but not on 2.2.  Am I not using this properly?

ICS:
[image]

2.2:

[image]

pref.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:persistent="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/android"
        android:title="check box" 
        android:key="akey">
    </CheckBoxPreference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Temp.java

```
public class Temp extends PreferenceActivity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state)
    {
        super.onCreate(state);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon attribute did not exist prior to Android 3.0.

If you look at the documentation for [Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setIcon%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) (which is extended by CheckBoxPreference), it says on the right side of the setIcon method that it was introduced in API 11 (Android 3.0).

Comment: i don't see that in the documentation?

Comment: Edited my answer to include the documentation.

Comment: But this is for the setIcon method, not for the icon attribute.

Comment: Same thing basically.  The attribute sets it in XML, the method sets it in code.  They both go to the same place.

Comment: Not really? The attribute exists since API 1, implying that setting in icon in XML is an option on all versions (though it seems to not work).  The methods were added in API 11, they will cause method not found exceptions if called prior to API 11.

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn't complain about unknown attributes, it just ignores them.  Whatever the case is, icons are not an option prior to Android 3.